# How to write a helm persistent-action to open a file at a particular line number?

Tags: helm, helm-sources

I have written a helm-extension that at the end shows a list of entries where each entry is like this:

> module_name function_name file-path line-number

I am now writing a persistent-action that will open the the file at a particular line number on each entry.

```
(defun decode-bt--open-file (line &optional persistent)
    (let ((file (match-string 3 line))
          (line-number (string-to-number (match-string 4 line)))
          (text (match-string 2 line)))
      (find-file (if (file-name-absolute-p file) file (concat dir file)))
      (goto-line (line-number))
      (if persistent (helm-highlight-current-line))))

(defun decode-backtrace-command ()
  (interactive)
  (setq backtrace-alist nil)
  (helm :sources '(some-helm-source)
        :truncate-lines t
        :action (lambda (line) (decode-bt--open-file line))
        :persistent-action (lambda (line) (decode-bt--open-file line t))
        :buffer "*helm backtrace*"))
```

This fails with the following error, `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure about the error. But the arguments `:action` and `:persistent-action` are part of the helm source itself, they doesn't work with the function `helm`.

Comment: nevertheless my function decode-bt--open-file is getting called. So I'm good. But the calling conventions seem to have a problem. and edebug doesn't show me local variables even if I press "v". Says it is not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defconst bt-decode--parse-regexp
    "^\\(?:.+ \\)\\{2\\}\\(.+\\) \\([0-9]+\\)")

(defun decode-bt--open-file (line &optional persistent)
  (when (string-match bt-decode--parse-regexp line)
    (let  ((filepath (match-string 1 line))
           (lineno (string-to-number (match-string 2 line))))
        (find-file-other-window filepath)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (forward-line (1- lineno))
        (helm-highlight-current-line))))
```